# How to increase watts going to my lithium battery?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging

I have a 48V 50Ah 2000W lithium battery for my ebike, I am currently using a 12V 160W solar panel with a GVB charge controller with MPPT and getting my battery to charge but only getting 350W, how can I get a full 2000W?

MPPT datasheet can be found [here](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0062/2959/0114/files/Genasun_GVB-8-WP_Datasheet-2018-1.pdf?5193887046331177433).

48V 50Ah Li-ion Battery pack is made of 16 pcs of 50000 mAh Li-ion Cells 
One Special 14 cells PCB with balance function is installed with battery pack to protect battery from over charging, over discharging and over drain

- Voltage: 48V (Rated voltage:51.2v)
- Capacity: 50Ah
- Cut-off voltage: 35V
- Max. discharging current: 100Amp
- Max Continuous Discharging Amperage: 50 Amps
- Rated Discharging Amperage: 50 Amps
- Charging Current: <10 Amps
- Charging Voltage: 58.8 Volts

Comment: Add a data sheet link for the battery (note that I don't mean a link to alibaba, ebay or amazon).

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, it is interesting you can even get a 350W output from a solar panel rated at 160W. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like your units are messed up.

Comment: https://genasun.eu/collections/genasun-lithium-mppts/products/genasun-gv-boost-8-lithium-56-8-volt-wp-mppt

Comment: Jack, you should really answer our questions because as of now, your question is difficult to understand. You want to produce 2000W from a 160W panel?

Comment: Looks like the 350W is the max panel power that the MPPT can convert.  Since you're using a 160W panel, 160W is the max you can get from the single panel.  You can go with two panels in parallel to give 320W max.  In order to get to 2000W, you would need a much larger MPPT and many more panels.

Comment: i agree, adding more panels would be helpful, but finding a mppt that can handle 2000w?

Comment: If the battery can only charge at less than 10A, then it can only charge at less than 10A. You can't charge it with 2000W @ 58V, that doesn't make sense. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Also note that this site is for questions related to electronics design and theory. Product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: I suspect that "2000 W" is supposed to be "2000 Wh", the nominal capacity of the battery. I also suspect that "350 W" is supposed to be "350 Wh", which is the amount of energy that the current setup is capable of putting into the battery in a day.

Answer (score 4):

In comment, you provided the following charge characteristics:

**Charging Current: <10 Amps Charging Voltage: 58.8 Volts**

58.8 volts times 10 amps sets an absolute charging power limit of 588 watts.

You cannot exceed this without exceeding the data sheet limits, and that is A Bad Thing.

In order to do this, you will need at least 4 160-watt solar panels, since 3 times 160 watts is 480 watts. Plus, your MPPT will not be 100% efficient, so you need to keep that in mind.

You will also need a better charger - one which can provide a charge current of 10 amps at 58 volts, or about 580 watts.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this down:

Solar Panel: you cannot get more power than this is giving you. That is your first bottle neck. This is limited to 160W maximum.

MPPT controller: this will give a maximum of 350W out. This is your second bottle neck, but it only have at most 160W going in.

Battery pack: you've told us the battery pack can only safely take 10A in. This is a third bottle neck.

You ask for how to put 2000W into your battery pack. The short answer is you can't. This may not be limited in your set up, but it is a safety limit. Putting power into a battery damages it, pushing in enough at one time can make the cells blow up. Usually cells are limited to a factor of their capacity. For instance a standard 18650 Li-Ion cell I've used in the pass was limited to charge at 2C, as in twice it's capacity. This is a high charge rate, usually they are 1C or even 0.5C. You've told us it's 10A, which is a very high current. At 48V, at 10A, that would give us 480W. Now, you wouldn't charge at 48V, as that's nominal charge for the battery, so call it 58V, so you've now got 580W. This is a lot lower than the 2000W you are asking for, but this is limit on the fastest the battery can be charged.

Now, to charge the battery as close to 2000W as you can, you want to push 580W into it. So, you need to achieve 580W out of your MPPT controller. Assuming your constant current source you are using to charge the battery keep the current at 10A, you want to make sure you have plenty of power out of the MPPT, so two of your 360W ones could feed the supply. Each of these MPPTs need to have a good 360W going into them, which means you need to have three of your 160W solar panels supplying them.

Your panels, and so your MPPT are all opreating at 12V. You need to boost this up to 58V, or whatever your charging with, so that it can then be used with a constant current supply to charge your pack. So a 12V to 58V booster is required. This would need to be as high efficiency as possible to keep your 580W.

**EDIT:** The specifications of your battery pack probably need some explaining too. As @Hearth mentioned, 2000W is the output capability of your pack. LiIon cells are non-symmetrical in their charge/discharge set up, while they can only take 1 or 1Amps in, they can out put significantly more. 2000W at 48V, would be 2000/48 = 41.6 Amps. You have a voltage of 48V, this is usually (but not always) the nominal voltage of the pack. The votlage of the  pack will vary from around 2.9V per cell (fully discharged), up to 4.2V per cell (fully charged). This means that to charge the pack up fully you need more than 48V, as shown in your updated question, 58.8V does the job. You've not mentioned the Wh of the pack, which is usually how pack are rated (as their voltage could be any combination of cells). Based on 48V, and 50Ah capacity, this would be 2400 Wh, which is useful to note as it means at max outputs (2000W) you pack will only last just over an hour. Also, at 2400 Wh, using your orignal 160 W panel, even before you take into account the losses due to inefficiencies, this will take you 2400/160 = 15 hours to charge up! If you push the pack to the limit, putting in 500W, you can get it charged up in about 5 hours.

TL:DR
You need more panels, more MPPTs, a booster circuit, and you can get to around a quarter of your desired 2000W.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the 2000W in the battery's speciifcations is quite likely its maximum *output*. In general, lithium batteries can discharge faster than they can charge, so this isn't unusual.

Comment: ok,,,lets try a different approach since I am limited on my current for charging,,,,what if I used the solar panels through my mppt to an ac inverter and use my ac battery chargers

Comment: @jackfarver you are limited either by the solar panel power (160W) or the charging current of the pack (580W). The only way to charge the pack faster is to use a different battery pack.